# Spree extension that fully supports multi-vendor marketplace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am trying to build an ecommerce marketplace. I am trying to add a multi-vendor functionality to a new Spree project. Vendors should be able to manage their Products, Stocks, Option Types, Orders...

Vendors will list their products. Shoppers will search for some products and can buy from one of the listed vendors.

I have checked some spree extensions that were rather old or didn't support all the functionality I need. I was wondering if there is an extension that fully supports adding vendors functionality to Spree.

Comment: did you find find anything ?!

Comment: No, we didn't find anything that fits with the requirements we have. We ended up building our own spree extension.